# Path.replace is not a function NPM SCSS AUTOPREFIXER build process

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, build

I'm trying to set up a sass build process. Basically, a compression, concatenation, prefixing, and compressing. I have a problem with autoprefixer package. At first, I couldn't do it because this version 10 have some bug and it is not compatible with postcss package. So I downgraded it to version @9.8.6 and here is the error I am getting.

-----PACKAGE.JSON---------

```
{
  "name": "natouros_website_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "landing page for natours",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "concat:css": "concat -o css/style.concat.css css/icon-font.css css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.0"
  }
}
```

-----TERMINAL ERROR------

```
> natouros_website_project@1.0.0 prefix:css C:\Users\M\Desktop\natouros_website_project
> postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css

TypeError: path.replace is not a function
    at module.exports (C:\Users\\Desktop\natouros_website_project\node_modules\slash\index.js:10:14)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\\Desktop\natouros_website_project\node_modules\postcss-cli\index.js:66:28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! natouros_website_project@1.0.0 prefix:css: `postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the natouros_website_project@1.0.0 prefix:css script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-01T10_28_16_713Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Mihailo\Desktop\natouros_website_project>
```

If needed I can also provide debug.log.

Answer (score 2):

Windows doesn't recognize single quotes. So replace the single quotes around the 'last 10 versions' with double quotes with escape characters (\"last 10 versions\").

See the following link for more information
https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli/issues/360